# Как удалить выбранную строку php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть вот такой вывод таблицы из MySql 
Как прописать удаление строки при нажатии на ссылку удалить

> ```
>  while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())[1]
>     {
>         print '<tr>
>                    <td>'.$rows ['first_name'].'</td>
>                    <td>'.$rows ['last_name'].'</td>   
>                    <td>'.$rows ['gender'].'</td>
>                    <td>'.$rows ['nationality'].'</td>  
>                    <td>'.$rows ['countries'].'</td>  
>                    <td>'.$rows ['adress'].'</td>
>                    <td>'.$rows ['passport'].'</td>
>                    <td>'.$rows ['phone'].'</td>  
>                    <td>'.$rows ['date_birsd'].'</td>     
>                    <td><a href="del_sportsmans.php">Удалить</a></td>
>          </tr>';
>     }
> ```

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]]

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, вам следует узнать, какое поле в таблице является уникальным идентификатором (id).

Далее обновите ссылку на удаление, добавив туда этот самый идентификатор (вместо 'id' подставьте нужное поле):

```
'<td><a href="del_sportsmans.php?id='.$rows['id'].'">Удалить</a></td>'
```

Логика файла del_sportsmans.php:

Получем id:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Делаем запрос на удаление:

```
DELETE FROM <имя таблицы> WHERE <идентификатор>=$id
```